# Using TypefaceSpan

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

I'm trying to make work TypefaceSpan [TypefaceSpan
on developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan)

The example, provided on that page, which uses **new TypefaceSpan(Typeface)** seems to be wrong now, because there is no such constructor. So I was trying to use **new TypefaceSpan(Parcel)** with no luck (I don't know how to correctly put Typeface in Parcel), and **new TypefaceSpan(String)** supports only system fonts (I could not make it work with custom font).

*Does anyone know, how to use TypefaceSpan with custom font (from res/font)?*

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

Declare variable like this:

```
  Typeface typeface;
```

Initialize variable like this:

```
 typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourFontName.ttf");
```

Set to the view like this:

```
 yourView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

above code is for setting font to the view.

For CustomTypeFaceSpan  add below class into your package.

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private final Typeface newType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
        super(family);
        newType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null) {
            oldStyle = 0;
        } else {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Use above class like this:

```
     Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/YourFontName.ttf");
     SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString("Your String Value");
     mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", typeface), 0, mNewTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
     yourView.setText(mNewTitle);
```